# Cannot read property 'openPicker' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image-picker

I have installed library using pod file.
used this library

https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

image selection from gallery working fine when I run code from x-code , but got above error when I run 'react-native run-ios'.

[image]

Any solution will be helpful.

Comment: Did you follow the [install guide](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) for adding the package to ios

Comment: @Craques yes exactly same

Comment: send me code...

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya Are you solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

**Reason for this error:**

The xcode could find the library in pods you need to install pods in order to make it work on iOS.

try running

```
pod install
```